# I'm keep getting REF error in all the cells that I paste the data to after writing the formula

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I wrote this code that will paste the first 7 columns from sheet2(sourcing) to sheet1(sheet1) and I also wrote a formula to every cell so if the code in the sourcing sheet changes then the one in sheet1 would change, but when I did that I got #REF! in every cell so I went to file --> settings and changed the calculations --> Iterative calculation from Off to On and the error was gone but i got 0 in every cell which isnt the right value of the cell.

Here is the code.

```
function moveCode() {
  try {
   const ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   const ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1A3tJiIEkDP_5R6mEY25IeAsO2XV_oveJwnUovxRd-1U");//or url whatever
   const ssh = ss1.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
   const dsh = ss2.getSheetByName('Sourcing');
   const lastRow = dsh.getLastRow();
   if (lastRow < 2) return;

   var srange = dsh.getDataRange();
   var formulas = [];
   var i=0;
   var j= 0;
   var row = null;
    // srange.getNumRows()-1 because skip the first row
   for( i=0; i<srange.getNumRows()-1; i++ ) {
      row = [];
      for( j=1; j<8; j++ ) {
        row.push("=Sheet1!"+String.fromCharCode(64+j)+(i+2).toString());  // A = 65
      }
      formulas.push(row);
    }
    ssh.getRange(2,1,formulas.length,formulas[0].length).setValues(formulas);
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}
```

I think there is something wrong with the formula but I'm not sure whats wrong.

If you need more explanation please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: Side note: Excel is *not* Google Sheets. Please only use the appropriate tags (you've mistakenly been using Excel and Excel-formula for several questions now).

Comment: ssh is Sheet1 and the formula is "Sheet1!".  This is recursive shouldn't one or the other be Sheet2?

Comment: Just noticed your using two different Spreadsheets. The formula will only work if both sheets are in the same Spreadsheet.

Comment: oh ok I see, Is there a way in this case to copy the data in a way it would be changed if the other spreadsheet changed?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your goal, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, how about using `IMPORTRANGE`? When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function moveCode() {
  try {
    const ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    const ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1A3tJiIEkDP_5R6mEY25IeAsO2XV_oveJwnUovxRd-1U");//or url whatever
    const ssh = ss1.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    const dsh = ss2.getSheetByName('Sourcing');
    const lastRow = dsh.getLastRow();
    if (lastRow < 2) return;
    ssh.getRange(2, 1).setFormula(`=IMPORTRANGE("${ss2.getUrl()}","'Sourcing'!A2:G${lastRow}")`);
  }
  catch (err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}
```

- After the formula was put in the cell, please accept for loading the values from the Spreadsheet.

#### References:

- [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340)
- [setFormula(formula)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula)

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I'm gonna try this out and let you know if it worked or not. Thank youu!

Comment: @Omar Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.